# How to promote QPdfview in Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqt6

I am trying to upgrade my PDF viewer on a form from QWebEngineView to QPdfView (PyQt6). I originally promoted QWebEngineView in the QT Designer without an issue but as far as PDF functionality its a bit limited so upgrading to QPdfView. I promoted using QWidget as base:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPdfView" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>109</x>
      <y>69</y>
      <width>291</width>
      <height>371</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>490</y>
      <width>79</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>530</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QPdfView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt6.QtPdfWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

However, when I try to load it using:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/serveracct/proj/promos/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/home/serveracct/proj/promos/main.py", line 10, in __init__
    uic.loadUi("test2.ui", self)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/load_ui.py", line 86, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/Loader/loader.py", line 62, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 1014, in parse
    self._handle_widget(ui_file.widget)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 842, in _handle_widget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(el)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 818, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 280, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 818, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 271, in createWidget
    self.stack.push(self._setupObject(widget_class, parent, elem))
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/uiparser.py", line 233, in _setupObject
    obj = self.factory.createQtObject(class_name, object_name,
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/objcreator.py", line 119, in createQtObject
    return self._cpolicy.instantiate(ctor, object_name, ctor_args,
  File "/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/Loader/qobjectcreator.py", line 145, in instantiate
    return ctor(*ctor_args, **ctor_kwargs)
TypeError: QPdfView(parent: Optional[QWidget]): not enough arguments
```

I tried promoting QPdfView in Qt Designer and tried to load the window using uic.loadUi()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "bug" (quotes required) caused by the fact that, unlike any other widget, the parent argument of QPdfView is required.

When child widgets are created by uic, they are always created with their parent in the constructor, using the `parent=[parent widget]` keyword.

PyQt classes are a bit peculiar, and their constructors don't behave exactly like normal Python classes.

Consider the following case:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        pass
```

With the above, doing `MyClass(parent=None)` will be perfectly valid.

The QPdfView constructor is the following:

```py
QPdfView(parent: Optional[QWidget])
```

This would make us think that using keyworded `parent` argument will be equally acceptable as using it as a positional one, but, in reality this won't work.

I suspect that the main problem relies on Qt, and PyQt just "fails" because it correctly follows the wrong signature: the parent shouldn't be mandatory, and that can be demonstrated by the fact that you can perfectly do `QPdfView(None)`.

There are two possible workarounds: fix the PyQt file that constructs the classes, or use a custom QPdfView subclass as a promoted widget.

### Fix `qobjectcreator.py`

The culprit is the `qobjectcreator.py` file; its path should be the following:

`<python-lib>/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/Loader/`.

Then go to the `instantiate()` function (around line 136) and insert the following before the `return`:

```py
        if ctor.__name__ == 'QPdfView' and 'parent' in ctor_kwargs:
            ctor_args = (ctor_kwargs.pop('parent'), )
```

### Use a promoted subclass

This is probably a better choice, as it doesn't require changing PyQt files and ensures compatibility for future versions.

Just create a QPdfView subclass like this:

```py
class MyPdfView(QPdfView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

Then use `MyPdfView` instead of QPdfView as class name for the promoted widget, using the file name as header.

You can even include that class in your main script, just ensure that you properly use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to create the QApplication.

Comment: An even simpler solution is to use `loadUiType`. This will follow a different code path which eventually calls `exec` on a generated Python module rather than creating objects dynamically. The real issue here is that the signature of QPdfView doesn't allow *keyword arguments*. The critical section is in *uic/uiparser.py* around line 230. The parser correctly assumes the parent is optional and creates a kwargs dict rather than an args tuple. Thus, strictly speaking, it's just doing exactly what the user told it to do (which was to create a subclass of QWidget).

Comment: Bah - in actual fact, `loadUiType` won't work either, because the generated module still produces a keyword argument. So when `setupUi` is called, the same problem will occur...

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh, that's interesting. I wanted to test `loadUiType` but then I completely forgot it, as I thought that having the keyword argument would break things in any case. Anyway, I've filed a [QTBUG-120313](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120313) as I believe that there's no valid reason for having it mandatory in the first place (as it shouldn't on QPdfDocument too). I'll send a report to the PyQt ml too.

Comment: @musicamante I was racking my brains out because the error message keep saying parent optional...promoted subclass worked. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottyCov You're welcome. I've seen your deleted answer, I don't know why it worked but since you deleted it you probably did something that made you believe it worked: from the class/inheritance point of view, PyQt6 and PySide6 are identical and only follow what Qt tells them: QPdfView is always a QAbstractScrollArea. Since Designer doesn't allow promotion of abstract classes, you must use the closest available ancestor, which is QFrame in this case. You cannot use another *derived* class like QScrollArea, because it's incompatible: it would be like promoting a QListView for a QTableView.